If in a closed system in equilibrium, $ΔG°=0$, why do we have the constant $K_p$ which is equal to 1?
If according to the below text, $ΔG°=0$ in equilibrium, therefore $K=1$, then why do we need equilibrium constants? ( Since according to the below equations $K$ is always equal to 1 in equilibrium) Is there something I don't know since I'm a beginner

$$ΔG°=−RTlnK$$ $$or$$ $$K=e^{−ΔG°/RT}$$
This form of the equation provides a useful link between these two essential thermodynamic properties, and it can be used to derive equilibrium constants from standard free energy changes and vice versa. The relations between standard free energy changes and equilibrium constants are summarized below


: Relations between Standard Free Energy Changes and Equilibrium Constants

|K  |ΔG°  |Comments                                                   |
|< 1| > 0 |Reactants are more abundant at equilibrium.                |
|= 1| = 0 |Reactants and products are equally abundant at equilibrium.|
|> 1|< 0  |Products are more abundant at equilibrium.                 |
Source ChemLibtext

$\Delta_r G^\circ = RT \ln{K}$ and $\Delta_r G = \Delta_r G^\circ + RT \ln{Q}$. While at equilibrium, $\Delta G = 0$. that is the huge difference.

@Poutnik but the article says K=1 in equilbrium so why not ΔrG∘=o?

K is not 1 in equilibrium, but a constant value

@Mäßige I am sory you are right. English is not my 1st language. I misunderstood the article

Don't apologize, learning something new is part of the process :)

The standerd change in gibbs energy ΔG°=RTlnK.
we can also write 0 as ln1.
In the above formula just substitute ln1in place of ΔG°
Using properties of log,we get 1 as our answer.

You may be confusing Standard Gibb’s with instantaneous Gibb’s energy change, and correspondingly Q with K. A is the reaction quotient, representing the instantaneous ratio of the concentration of products raised to the stoichiometric coefficients to that of the reactants. Correspondingly, the equation is that: Instantaneous Gibb’s = Standard Gibbs + RTlnQ. Standard Gibbs is only defined under standard conditions - notably including 1M concentrations (hence not an equilibrium unless the equilibrium constant is equal to 1). At equilibrium we have Q=K and so the instantaneous Gibb’s =0 - I.e. the system is at equilibrium so no change in either direction is more favourable than the other way. Q is an instantaneously defined parameter, without a standard value, whereas K is a constant at a given temperature.

Seems this answer will only add to the OPs confusion with this statement: "Standard Gibbs is only defined under standard conditions - notably including 1M concentrations (hence not an equilibrium unless the equilibrium constant is equal to 1)". If I interpret the statement corrrectly you are saying precisely what the OP intiially thought was true, that K=1 at equilibrium.
